# I wanted to make a blog in pure react js and Nodejs(express,mongodb) . Also i can post code snippets and heading rather than a simple text

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

An example of a blogpost
[Example of Blog post](https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2022-05/use-deferred-value/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use pure React, you might want to use something like Create React App, or Vite + React. You can pull in a Markdown library like react-markdown to parse blog posts.

I would also recommend using something like Astro (https://astro.build/), which can parse markdown and React natively.

Answer (score -1):

you could use libraries like CKEditor, and Quill for advanced editors where you could add some images, and code snippets. and send the value of that editor to your server.

but you might like react-markdown if you don't like editors.